# Websphere, single EAR with multiple WAR's, jersey

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, websphere, jax-rs, ear

I'm having trouble having multiple java web applications run on a single server.  The stack I'm using is:

- Eclipse JavaEE Kepler
- Jersey 2.0
- Apache Tomcat 7
- Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5
- JDK 1.7

Here are the symptoms:

1. Both web applications run together perfectly fine in Tomcat
2. Both web applications run perfectly fine when only one web application running on Websphere
3. When both application try to run together, the server hangs.  No error pages, nothing.  Nothing in the console.  Going to a dummy URL doesn't give me a 404
4. Context roots are different for each web application: the console messages: [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available
   (default_host): http://localhost:9080/myproject/ message for both
   applications
5. I can't stop the server once I start with multiple web applications. It basically stays on the "stopping" state until I kill the java process manually.
6. I get outofmemory permgen errors after a few minutes (running both only)

Things I've tried:

- Single EAR with both WAR's added to server
- Both WAR's independently added to server
- specifying different context roots in the ibm-web-ext.xml for both projects
- both projects have their own .jars in the WEB-INF lib folder for jersey

I'm kind of stumped on this one.  Since they both run fine on Tomcat, I'm guessing it's some configuration issue with Websphere, but I've poked around and didn't really see anything...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the error message you get at the logs or stdout ?

Comment: After a few minutes, I start getting outofmemoryerrors for permgen space.      Also, I can't stop the server without killing the java process if I'm trying to run both.  This happens regardless of whether I get these memory errors.

Comment: There could be some lock or contention of resources. You might need to debug further where the lock is. Get the stack trace of the hanging process or application (kill -3 javaProcessid)

Comment: If you don't use specific Jersey features, you could try to remove Jersey jars as latest Liberty provides JAX-RS 2.0 implementation.